# How can I exclude certain overlay-derived directories from my war using maven?

Tags: maven

We build a webapp using maven 3.5.0 and the maven-war-plugin.  We have many overlays, many of which have a `tests` directory that contains JSP files used for testing certain things in a dev environment.  We don't want these included in our war.

We tried the following:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <overlays>...</overlays>
        <warSourceExcludes>tests</warSourceExcludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This didn't work, nor did a couple of `configuration` variations:

```
<packagingExcludes>tests</packagingExcludes>
```

and

```
<packagingExcludes>**/${project.artifactId}/tests/**</packagingExcludes>
```

Is this due to my naive misuse of configuration options, or does it have to do with how overlays are processed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `dependentWarExcludes` element worked to eliminate the `tests` directories and their contents:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <overlays>...</overlays>
        <dependentWarExcludes>tests/**</dependentWarExcludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `<excludes>..</excludes>` (see https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html) instead of `<packagingExcludes>..</packagingExclude>`...

```
 ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <overlays>
            <overlay>
              <groupId>com.example.projects</groupId>
              <artifactId>documentedprojectdependency</artifactId>
              <excludes>
                <exclude>WEB-INF/classes/images/sampleimage-dependency.jpg</exclude>
              </excludes>
            </overlay>
          </overlays>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
```

Comment: So, it sounds there is no way to have a common exclude statement that excludes a certain directory from every overlay.  Instead, I need to have repetitive excludes statements in each overlay specification?

Comment: The question is why is it packaged into the WAR at all if you need to exclude it later ? Maybe it would make sense to make a separate WAR file which only contains the things you need a kind of common-war ..?